# SQL - how to retrieve mutlple rows from a table, and then take that info and dump it into a new row on a different table

Tags: sql, database, insert-into

I want to take rows from one table, based on a typeID number, and insert a new row into a different table using a mix of data from the first table query and some static variables .

Is there a easy way to do this?

Code edit:  (I cannot get this to work - get a MIssing Expression error )

```
Insert into tableOne
(pk_col, Custom_int_col, Data_from_other_col)
Select  default,111,security_resource_id
From security_resource sr
Where sr.company_id = 1
```

Comment: Is default a column name, if so it's also a keyword, so you'll want to wrap it in ", [] or ` s as per back end's preference

Comment: the issue here was that the table had a sequence.nextval function, so instead of using default keyword, i had to call tablename.nextval for the pk_col

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
Insert SomeTable(SomeCol1, SomeCol2,SomeCol29)
Select 'SomeText', SomeCol3,963.45 From SomeOtherTable Where SomeKey = 876
```

There's another flavour called `select into` as well. Can't get exact with the syntax, because you never mentioned which DBMS you are using.

Comment: using oracle sql developer for this one.  I will give your code a shot

Answer (score 2):

yes sure

```
    INSERT INTO yourTable
    (column1,column2)
    SELECT '' ,column FROM SecondTa
```

Answer (score 1):

If the second table doesn't exist, you can create it using either `create table as` or `select into`, depending on the database you are using.

For instance:

```
select col1, 123 as value
into NewTable
from t
where flag = 0
```

In some databases, the syntax would be:

```
create table as
    select col1, 123 as value
    from t
    where flag = 0
```

Tony already answered the question for the situation where the second table already exists.